# What's the SharePoint applications pool limit depend on?

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, application-pool

I am working on SharePoint 2013, with a number of the application pool is 10.

I gonna to create a new service application that requires new application pool , I read that the limit is 10,

Can I increase the application pool limit and what is depend on !?

Thanks

Comment: What's your farm topology ?

Comment: 2-size farm 1WFE+ application and 1 database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limit is dependent largely upon:

- The amount of memory allocated to the web servers
- The workload that the farm is serving, that is, the user base and the usage characteristics (a single highly active application pool can utilize 10 GB or more)

You can also, check [Comparing Application Pool limits in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint 2013 /2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/10/compare-sharepoint-2016-application-pool-limits-with-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

As per MSFT guidelines and industry recommendations, one farm should not have more than 10 App pools.

You shouldn't cap the memory utilization of app pool, an app pool grows upto tons of GB and which will put your farm in risk. All app pool reserve the memory and other system resource. I had an experience where memory is 64 gb with 10 app pools and all the time with moderate load we got performance issues and noticed one of the app pool gone crazy.

Why not you combine your web applications under one app loop, you will save the system resources and room for services. Btw this is how msft implemented in sharepoint online.

To combine app pools for web application check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/12/19/consolidate-sharepoint-2010-application-pools/)

Comment: What about application services application pools can I combined it also !!!

Comment: As far I know I think it is not recommended for services.